# What does the second column in the gdb stack trace mean?

Tags: gdb, stack-trace

I have a stack trace that looks like this:

```
#3  0x00007fffde86c206 in GetMedia (p_ml=0xb91560, id=<value optimized out>, select=ML_MEDIA, reload=<value optimized out>) at ../../../modules/media_library/sql_media_library.c:1170
#4  0x00007fffde86a7d0 in GetInputItemFromMedia (p_ml=0xb91560, i_media=12276000) at ../../../modules/media_library/sql_media_library.c:1204
#5  0x00007ffff6765eab in ml_CreateInputItem (this=0x7784f0) at ../../../../include/vlc_media_library.h:887
#6  MLModel::popupInfo (this=0x7784f0) at ../../../../modules/gui/qt4/components/playlist/media_library/ml_model.cpp:528
#7  0x00007ffff67a7204 in MLModel::qt_metacall (this=0x7784f0, _c=<value optimized out>, _id=17710, _a=<value optimized out>) at components/playlist/media_library/ml_model.moc.cpp:79
#8  0x00007ffff4ec8e3f in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**) () from /usr/lib/libQtCore.so.4
```

I'm wondering that the second column signifies. Also, what does the lack of it signify? As can be seen, frame #6 does not have this address, and I believe my problem( a segfault ) is being caused due to something related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That column contains the return address from the called function just above to the caller function on that line. Its lack probably means that the function was inlined.